# CSV to Mongo using mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv, mongoose, schema

I'm attempting to get a CSV file to my mongodb collection (via mongoose) **while checking for matches at each level of my schema**.

So for a given schema `personSchema` with a nest schema `carSchema`:

```
repairSchema = {
  date: Date,
  description: String
}
carSchema = {
  make: String,
  model: String
}
personSchema = {
  first_name: String,
  last_name: String,
  car: [carSchema]
}
```

and an object that I am [mapping the CSV data to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244587/map-array-to-object-with-depth-based-on-separate-object):

```
mappingObject = {
  first_name : 0,
  last_name: 1,
  car : {
    make: 2,
    model: 3,
    repair: {
      date: 4,
      description: 5
    }
  }
}
```

check my collection for a match then check each nested schema for a match or create the entire document, as appropriate.

**Desired process:**

I need to check if a person document matching `first_name` and `last_name` exists in my collection.

If such a person document exists, check if that person document contains a matching `car.make` and `car.model`.

If such a car document exists, check if that car document contains a matching `car.repair.date` and `car.repair.description`.

If such a repair document exists, do nothing, exact match to existing record.

If such a repair document does not exist, push this repair to the repair document for the appropriate car and person.

If such a car document does does not exist, push this car to the car document for the appropriate person.

If such a person document does not exist, create the document.

**The kicker**

This same function will be used across many schemas, which **may be nested many levels deep** (current database has one schema that goes 7 levels deep). So it has to be fairly abstract. **I can already get the data into the structure I need as a javascript object**, *so I just need to get from that object to the collection as described*.

It also has to be synchronous, since multiple records from the CSV could have the same person, and asynchronous creation could mean that the same person gets created twice.

**Current solution**

I run through [each line of the CSV](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line), map the data to my `mappingObject`, then step through each level of the object in javascript, checking non-object key-value pairs for a match using `find`, then pushing/creating or recursing as appropriate. This absolutely works, but it is painfully slow with such large documents.

Here's my full recursing function, which works:

`saveObj` is the object that I've mapped the CSV on to that matches my schema.

`findPrevObj` is initially false. `path` and `topKey` both are initially `""`.

`lr` is the line reader object, `lr.resume` simply moves on to the next line.

```
var findOrSave = function(saveObj, findPrevObj, path, topKey){
    //the object used to search the collection
    var findObj = {};

    //if this is a nested schema, we need the previous schema search to match as well
    if (findPrevObj){
        for (var key in findPrevObj){
            findObj[key] = findPrevObj[key];
        }
    }

    //go through all the saveObj, compiling the findObj from string fields
    for (var key in saveObj){
        if (saveObj.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof saveObj[key] === "string"){
            findObj[path+key] = saveObj[key]
        }
    }


    //search the DB for this record
    ThisCollection.find(findObj).exec(function(e, doc){

        //this level at least exists
        if (doc.length){

            //go through all the deeper levels in our saveObj
            for (var key in saveObj){
                var i = 0;
                    if (saveObj.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof saveObj[key] === "string"){
                        i += 1;
                        findOrSave(saveObj[key], findObj, path+key+".", path+key);
                    }   

                    //if there were no deeper levels (basically, full record exists)        
                    if (!i){
                        lr.resume();
                    }
                }

        //this level doesn't exist, add new record or push to array
            } else {

                if (findPrevObj){

                    var toPush = {};
                    toPush[topKey] = saveObj;

                    ThisCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
                        findPrevObj,
                        {$push: toPush},
                        {safe: true, upsert: true},
                        function(err, doc) {
                            lr.resume();
                        }
                    )   
                } else {
                    // console.log("\r\rTrying to save: \r", saveObj, "\r\r\r");
                    ThisCollection.create(saveObj, function(e, doc){
                        lr.resume();
                    });
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do here? my understanding from the first section is that you have a csv that has columns in the format `first_name,last_name,car_make,car_model` and you want to loop through every line creating a person. if that's the case, I don't understand why you need  to do `Person.find`...is there some kind of unique constraint here?

Comment: I think you need to rewrite everything after "I currently have this working", it's quite unclear what your problem is...also, can you be a bit more concrete with your data structure? how do those nested levels look like?

Comment: use this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson convert all data to json , then restructure your data according to schema ?

Comment: @jtmarmon I'll update for clarity, but the person.find is to check if a person with a matching first and last name exists. If they do exist, I check each car for a match - if the car exists already, there's no reason to add this record. If the car doesn't exist, I push it to the car array for the matching person. 

If no person was matched, I'd save the entire new record.

Comment: @aishwatsingh I tried that module, it worked great for getting the csv file parsed and the data into the structure I wanted, but that's not the issue. I couldn't get mongo/mongoose to check if the existing data for partial matches (for instance, match person, then if matched look for car, else create new record.) It simply creates an entirely new record every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'll update for clarity, but the person.find is to check if a person with a matching first and last name exists. If they do exist, I check each car for a match - if the car exists already, there's no reason to add this record. If the car doesn't exist, I push it to the car array for the matching person. If no person was matched, I'd save the entire new record.

Ah, what you want is to update with upsert:

replace

```
Person.find({first_name: "adam", last_name: "snider"}).exec(function(e, d){
  //matched? check {first_name: "adam", last_name: "snider", car.make: "honda", car.model: "civic"}

  //no match? create this record (or push to array if this is a nested array) 

});
```

with

```
Person.update(
    {first_name: "adam", last_name: "snider"}, 
    {$push: {car: {make: 'whatever', model: 'whatever2'}}}, 
    {upsert: true}
)
```

If a match is found, it will push into OR create the `car` field this subdoucment: `{car_make: 'whatever', car_model: 'whatever2'}`.

If a match is not found, it will create a new doc that looks like:

`{first_name: "adam", last_name: "snider", car: {car_make: 'whatever', car_model: 'whatever2'}}`

This cuts your total db round trips in half. However, for even more efficiency, you can use an [orderedBulkOperation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp). This would result in a *single* round trip to the database.

Here's what that would look like (using [es6](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/) here for concision...not a necessity):

```
const bulk = Person.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
lr.on('line', function(line) {
  const [first_name, last_name, make, model, repair_date, repair_description] = line.split(',');
  // Ensure user exists
  bulk.update({first_name, last_name}, {first_name, last_name}, {upsert: true});

  // Find a user with the existing make and model. This makes sure that if the car IS there, it matches the proper document structure
  bulk.update({first_name, last_name, 'car.make': make, 'car.model': model}, {$set: {'car.$.repair.date': repair_date, 'car.$.repair.description': repair_description}});

  // Now, if the car wasn't there, let's add it to the set. This will not push if we just updated because it should match exactly now.
  bulk.update({first_name, last_name}, {$addToSet: {car: {make, model, repair: {date: repair_date, description: repair_description}}}})
});
```

Comment: I was looking at this function before (update + upsert). How does this work with a deeper set of nested schemas? For instance, if `car` already exists but has an array of `repairs` linked to yet another schema needed to be pushed? If there's an example of the next level, I can probably pick it apart for my more abstract use case.

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question, but if the `car` field has an array of objects, upsert will just push the make and model into that same array, indiscriminate of the contents of that array

Comment: the first paragraph of that section reads like gibberish to me...can you give some more concrete info on what those structures look like and how they impact the data import? regarding the asynchronousness, this is an `orderedBulkOperation`, meaning that it works in the order you perform the operations

Comment: i see now. you can include multiple queries in your find like `.find({first_name, last_name, 'car.model': car_model, 'car.make': car_make})`

Comment: So I would still need to run a query for each level of nested document, but at least it would be one less round trip. I posted my current code above.

Comment: it seems you'd need an upsert operation per row, because if i understand you correctly each row knows the lookup info (in the case of your original example, first_name and last_name) and the update info (car_make and car_model). if there's more info in the csv row, you can just include the car make and car model in the lookup info and add whatever you need to the `$push` instead. as long as you can get it to be all upserts (which i think you can) this will be _far_ more efficient than your original code because of the bulk operation which only makes one round trip

Comment: But I wouldn't know which to match off the top. I don't know if that person has that car or not, and then I don't know if that car has that repair or not. So I can't just have one find and one update, I have to check each level of my object (forget the CSV for a second). My data could be nested through several levels.

Comment: ok, makes sense. you could have multiple upserts then. upsert the car, then upsert the repair. then you guarantee it's there

Comment: Is there a way to do that in one call, or do you still need to do one update per upsert?

Comment: one update per upsert. with bulk operation it doesn't matter nearly as much, though

Comment: after giving the question another look i realized i was missing something. the updated code should do what you need

Comment: Will each `bulk.update` be synchronous inside the `lr.on()` callback?

Comment: none of the updates execute until you call `execute` at the end. when you call `update` on the `bulk` object it simply queues it to be executed after `execute` is called

Comment: so because you're using an ordered bulk operation, they are in essence synchronous

Comment: I haven't had the time to try to implement this in my code yet (my actual code is very abstract, one functionality to work with many collections). It will probably be Monday before I can get to it, but this looks very promising.

Comment: This is faster using bulk, however, that may be subjective. Doing this with your bulk method requires one update for each level of the object regardless of whether it exists or not - my method only requires deeper level querying if each other level already exists. So... more database calls, but also faster ones.